# How to remove default style for thead in css?

Tags: jquery, css

I am implementing the table sorter. So that added `thead` before `tr` tag.
default my table having some default style. If i am placing the thead before `tr` header colors are changing.
Please tell me how to remove the default `thead` styles ?

Comment: Add your current css code please

Comment: just liked this table thead tr{// here css } ..

Answer (score 2):

```
thead, thead tr, thead tr td, thead tr th
{
    background-color: none !important;
    /* you can define a custom color as well */
    background-color: #aabbcc;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

For IE7 type the following code into the `head` section

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link href="IEold.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

And put the appropriate css rules into IEold.css file. Maybe the solution could be writing

```
/*IEold.css*/
background-color: transparent;
```

Comment: if i am adding the above css ,table sorter images are not loading.

Comment: in ie9 working fine the above css background-color:none but ie7 showing problem not displaying anything.

Comment: please check my css in above.

Comment: use `background-color:transparent` so it will keep the image, and remove the solid color

Answer (score 0):

Try to erase the thead from the css rule, and add a new rule like this:

```
 thead
    {

        /* you can define your new color for the thead */
        background-color: #aabbcc;
        font-size:1.3em;
    }

thead tr, thead tr td
    {
        background: none !important;
        /* you can define a custom color as well */
        background-color: #aabbcc;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```